# How to read uid of the CMSParagraphComponent on the View

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

[Here is](https://answers.sap.com/questions/12966119/how-to-render-component-uid-name-of-a-custom-compo.html) what I exactly want to achieve but didn't have an answer. What's best practice to get the uid of CMSParagraphComponent on the storefront?

**DefaultCMSComponentService**

```
protected Collection<String> getEditorProperties(AbstractCMSComponentModel component, boolean readableOnly) {
    String code = component.getItemtype();
    if (!this.cEditorProperties.containsKey(code)) {
        LOG.debug("caching editor properties for CMSComponent [" + component.getItemtype() + "]");
        List<String> props = new ArrayList();
        Collection<String> systemProps = this.getSystemProperties(component);
        Set<AttributeDescriptorModel> attributeDescriptors = this.getTypeService()
                .getAttributeDescriptorsForType(this.getTypeService().getComposedTypeForCode(code));
        Iterator var8 = attributeDescriptors.iterator();

        while (true) {
            AttributeDescriptorModel ad;
            String qualifier;
            do {
                do {
                    if (!var8.hasNext()) {
                        this.cEditorProperties.put(code, props);
                        return (Collection) this.cEditorProperties.get(code);
                    }

                    ad = (AttributeDescriptorModel) var8.next();
                    qualifier = ad.getQualifier();
                } while (systemProps.contains(qualifier));
            } while (readableOnly && !ad.getReadable());

            props.add(qualifier);
        }
    } else {
        return (Collection) this.cEditorProperties.get(code);
    }
}


public Collection<String> getSystemProperties(AbstractCMSComponentModel component) {
    String code = component.getTypeCode();
    if (!this.cSystemProperties.containsKey(code)) {
        LOG.debug("caching system properties for CMSComponent [" + component.getTypeCode() + "]");
        List props = null;

        try {
            props = (List) Registry.getApplicationContext().getBean(code + "SystemProperties");
        } catch (NoSuchBeanDefinitionException var5) {
            LOG.debug("No bean found for : " + code + "SystemProperties", var5);
            props = this.getSystemProperties();
        }

        this.cSystemProperties.put(code, props);
    }

    return (Collection) this.cSystemProperties.get(code);
}
```

It's not being populated because it's considered as the system property. Hence, as per the above logic system property will not be consider as redable property.

Now question is, How hybris get the list of system property for the given type? In another words, where this `Registry.getApplicationContext().getBean(code + "SystemProperties")` bean declare?

---

**EDIT:** The fact I know is, if Property attribute of AttributeDescriptor is set to false then it consider as system property. But when I checked for uid AttributeDescriptor, it (Property attribute) already set true.

Answer (score 1):

There are some functionalities oob in hybris that uses the uid inside a view. For example the `SearchPageController`. To be more specific, let's take a look at this method :

```
private static final String COMPONENT_UID_PATH_VARIABLE_PATTERN = "{componentUid:.*}";
...
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/autocomplete/" + COMPONENT_UID_PATH_VARIABLE_PATTERN, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public AutocompleteResultData getAutocompleteSuggestions(...){

final SearchBoxComponentModel component = (SearchBoxComponentModel) cmsComponentService.getSimpleCMSComponent(componentUid);

}
```

The actual `COMPONENT_UID_PATH_VARIABLE_PATTERN` value is in the `searchboxcomponent.jsp` :

```
<spring:url value="/search/autocomplete/{/componentuid}" var="autocompleteUrl" htmlEscape="false">
      <spring:param name="componentuid"  value="${component.uid}"/>
</spring:url>
```

How does this work? Every time you type something, a call to this endpoint is made, with the component uid extracted using `${component.uid}`.

Why does this work? Let's take a look at the `productLayout1Page.jsp` and take a simple tag from there:

```
<cms:pageSlot position="CrossSelling" var="comp" element="div" class="productDetailsPageSectionCrossSelling">
    <cms:component component="${comp}" element="div" class="productDetailsPageSectionCrossSelling-component"/>
</cms:pageSlot>
```

Now we see that there is a `<cms:component component=${..}.../>` tag which reference a component instance and you can access it using `${component.attributeName}` inside the component's jsp.

Answer (score 0):

It seems not easy to get the `uid` on the storefront. But I have managed it like this

- Create a dynamic attribute and return `uid` value from the getter method
- Now you can populate this dynamic attribute on the frontend